# How to check if all PC programs are using the VPN's IP?

Tags: web-application, privacy, web-browser, vpn, anonymity

With browsers you can go to websites that specifically check your IP to see if your VPN's IP is there. But how do you check if all the other programs or applications on your computer are going through the VPN using the VPN's IP address? Is there anything that would cause a program to use your real IP instead of the VPN's IP?

Comment: Depending on operating system, you could add firewall rules to ensure no traffic escapes the VPN. You can also confirm that the VPN is working for all traffic by using Wireshark.

Comment: What would I need to do to set rules for a Windows Firewall to only allow traffic through the VPN?

Answer (score 2):

In general, IP routing isn't program specific, but  the *next-hop* is selected based on the *routing table*, in this order:

1. Destination address matches a directly connected network.
2. The routing table contains specific route for the destination network.
3. Default gateway.

Depending on the VPN implementation it might add routes that falls into category 2 or a default gateway with a lower metric value. The real IP might be exposed if the routing table contains a better route through that interface. Also, if communication to *private networks* (`10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16`) is possible, it never uses the VPN.

This also means that the results from whatismyip.com and alternatives might not be globally true even on the web browser. Check your routing table and learn to interpret it.

Also, any program using networking automatically without actions from the user will continue making connections when the VPN is down. Many websites do this, too; don't leave your browser open unattended.